# I would like to create a custom-made "class" for my lab reports

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing

I regularly write chemistry lab reports. Over time, I figured which packages to use. However, I would like to write some sort of superclass (like in C++) so the following code is read in the directory, but not inserted in the file.
I would greatly appreciate to be redirected to the right info. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

%Set the dimensions of the document
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, pgfplots, textcomp,lscape}


%Bibliography style and source
\usepackage{achemso}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./references.bib}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Image path directory
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=10pt,aboveskip=10pt}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%Load math + SI packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Make cell space, scientific notation, and standard units
\usepackage{cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
%setup graphics path

%Create the header file. Important: don't insert blank space between the minipage to get them aligned
\begin{minipage}[]{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Concordia_Logo2.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[]{10cm}
  \begin{flushright}
  Johnathan\\
  \underline{Student ID:} 123456\\
  Laboratory report \#4\\
  CHEM221\\
 \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{3em}
\centerline{\Large\textbf{Liquid-liquid extraction: purification of benzoic acid}}

\tableofcontents

\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

**Reply to cfr's answer**

EDIT:
@cfr Hi! Thank you!! However, when I do the following:

```
\RequirePackage{achemso}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
%\RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

I get:
     .\references.bib

at the top of the minipage. It's like the references.bib is not read (with something similar to biber), no? Thank you! :)

Comment: You have 2 `\begin{document}` lines.

Comment: Are you trying to [design your own class/style file](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2011/03/27/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-your-own-cv.html)? It's definitely a good idea in this case.

Comment: You can't use achemso and Biblatex. Which do you want to use?

Comment: It is a question of which you want to use. If you want to use `achemso`, then you don't want Biber/Biblatex and `\addbibresource{}` is not right. In that case, you want `\bibliography{references}` in the body of your document, where the bibliography should go.

Comment: Please see edited answer. I've added `\printbibliography` for the Biblatex/Biber option and added some comments indicating how to change your document if using achemso/BibTeX instead.

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much for your help! :D I truly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

`mypackage.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{setspace}

%Set the dimensions of the document
\RequirePackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx, pgfplots, textcomp,lscape}

%Bibliography style and source
% \RequirePackage{achemso}% or comment out biblatex
% \bibliographystyle{achemso}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{xfrac}
\RequirePackage{changes}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=10pt,aboveskip=10pt}

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

%Load math + SI packages
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}

%Make cell space, scientific notation, and standard units
\RequirePackage{cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\renewcommand*\maketitle{%
  \begin{minipage}[]{5cm}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{tiger}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[]{10cm}
    \begin{flushright}
      \@author\par
      \underline{Student ID:} \@studentid\par
      Laboratory report \#\@reportno\par
      \@classno\par
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}
  \bigskip\par
  \begin{center}
    \Large\bfseries\@title
  \end{center}%
}
\newcommand*\@studentid{}
\newcommand*\@reportno{}
\newcommand*\@classno{}
\newcommand*\studentid[1]{\renewcommand*\@studentid{#1}}
\newcommand*\reportno[1]{\renewcommand*\@reportno{#1}}
\newcommand*\classno[1]{\renewcommand*\@classno{#1}}
\endinput
```

Document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
%setup graphics path
\addbibresource{./references.bib}% comment this line out if using achemso/BibTeX rather than Biblatex/Biber
%Image path directory
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\title{Liquid-liquid extraction: purification of benzoic acid}
\author{Johnathan}
\studentid{123456}
\reportno{4}
\classno{CHEM221}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\onehalfspacing

\section{Introduction}

\printbibliography% comment out for achemso/BibTeX
%\bibliography{references}% uncomment for achemso/BibTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: make it a class is better (I think)

Comment: @Johnathan such an edit belongs in your question, not in cfr's answer! Rejecting it and moving it to the question.

Comment: @cfr I placed OP's reply in the question. It does not fit inside a comment, I fear.

Comment: @MickG My apologies! I didn't mean any disrespect! Thank you for pointing this out, so I do not commit the error in subsequent posts! :)

Comment: @Johnathan we are all here to learn, about the site and about LaTeX. To err is human, but to persevere is diabolic (says an Italian saying). Don't worry, it wasn't disrespectful, just out of place :). Good evening.

Comment: And PS, we'd better stop the conversation, because this kind of comments is not very well looked upon, since it isn't about the post :).

Comment: @touhami Why? I tend to use a class if there's some reason a package would be awkward and a package otherwise. Generally, that means that I use a class if I want to pass options at that point and a package otherwise. But this is probably just habit: I'm not sure when a class is a better option, I guess. How do you make that decision?

Comment: Page 5 `Is it a class or package?` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide. (but I am not sure)

Comment: @touhami Thanks. But these commands *could* be used with `report.cls` or `book.cls`, for example, couldn't they? It is true that they could not be used with just *any* class, but that is true of many, many packages.

Comment: you may be right.

Comment: @touhami I may be wrong.

Comment: I end up translating "Is it a class or a package?" to "Does it have a mandatory format or not?" Assuming there's always these margins, this logo in the title, etc., I'd say it should be a class.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I can see that. I guess I tend to think of it in terms of flexibility and convenience. Here, a package increases flexibility without any inconvenience. So I don't see the need to make it a class, which would make it less flexible and no more convenient. (Except you'd have to type one line fewer, but that really seems trivial.)